# Can I use ```this``` at advantage for writing conditions for if statements?

Tags: javascript, button, conditional-statements, this, addeventlistener

I'd like to condition the hovering of buttons to perform exclusive tasks respective to each button. The if statement does not work as I intended, it still prints `mouseover` events for all buttons when I want it to print on condition that it's the first button. I will later write separate tasks under conditions for the other buttons.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('play');
var span = document.getElementById('span');

function clearSpan() {
  span.innerHTML = "";
}

// consolidation attempt for hover on
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('mouseover', printHoverOn);
}

// consolidation attempt for hover off
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener('mouseout', printHoverOff);
}

function printHoverOn(e) {
  cursor = this.id;
  if (cursor === 'firstButton') {
    span.innerHTML = "January";
    console.log(this.id + " is hovered");
  } else if (cursor === 'secButton') {
    span.innerHTML = "February";
    console.log(this.id + " is hovered");
  } else {
    console.log("nothing to print");
  }

}

function printHoverOff(e) {
  console.log(this.id + " was hovered");
  clearSpan();
  cursor = null;
}
```

```html
<button id="firstButton" class="play"></button>
<button id="secButton" class="play"></button>
<button id="thirdButton" class="play"></button>
<button id="fourthButton" class="play"></button>
<button id="fifthButton" class="play"></button>
<button id="sixthButton" class="play"></button>
<button id="seventhButton" class="play"></button>
<span id="span">Change Me</span>
```

Does anyone have ideas to help enhance my logic here? Thank you

I wrote longer script with an eventlistener for each button but I wish to shorten the code and, in process, began using the script I have now.

Comment: `cursor === 'firstButton'` instead of `cursor = firstButton`. Also your codepen link does not work.

Comment: Thanks @m51, I updated the question with a proper link

Comment: What's wrong with `evt.currentTarget.id`?

Comment: Same answer as the dupe, use `currentTarget`. You could bind `this` with `.bind` or by using a closure but there's no reason to do so.

Comment: PS, try always to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` eventNames.

Comment: @Jared Smith thanks. I'll try this next in my future updates